# How to place coordinates of turning point and y intercept on a graph of a parabola?

Tags: positioning

I'm generating the graph of a parabola as part of several graphs. I'd like to show the coordinates of the turning point and the y-intercept of the parabola below the turning point and to the right of the y-intercept. I'm using the following packages: amsfonts, pgfplots, pgfplotslibrary{polar}, pgflibrary{shapes.geometric}, tikzlibrary{calc}.

How do I calculate the position for the sets of coordinates on the graph? Just specifying the actual coordinates for this specific function didn't work.

This is my code for the parabola:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[name=plot1, axis x line = middle, axis y line = middle, xticklabels=\empty,
yticklabels=\empty, xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, axis equal, ymin=-3, ymax=4]
\addplot[samples=100]{(x+2)^2-1};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Better than list of used packages is extend your code fragment to complete, compilable small document with your image.  Points on parabola you can determine as `(x,{f(x)})`, where `f(x)` is parabola equation. How to determine some particular `x` is math problem, not LaTeX. However, some points you can determine by use of  `intersections` library for example as intersections of parabola and coordinate axis.

Comment: OK thanks. Any chance you could provide an example code that I may use?

Answer (score 1):

Your question and comment to it is not entirely clear. I can't provide your code since it is unknown to me. However, I can extend your code fragment to an MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but compilable document with your code fragment. Is this a problem?

Use of the `intersections` library for determining of interceptions points of parabola with coordinates is as follows:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
dot/.style = {circle, fill=red, inner sep=1.6pt},
every label/.append style = {inner sep=1pt}
                        ]
\begin{axis}[name=plot1, 
    axis lines = middle, 
    xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty, 
    xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, 
    axis equal,
    enlarge y limits={0.1,upper}, 
    ymin=-1.5, ymax=4,
    no marks, samples=100
            ]
\addplot+[name path=P]{(x+2)^2-1};
%
\path[name path=X]  (-5,0) -- (0,0);
\path[name path=Y]  (0,0) -- (0,4);
%
\path[name intersections={of = P and X, by={x1,x2}}] 
    node[dot,label=255:$x_1$] at (x1)  {}
    node[dot,label=285:$x_2$] at (x2)  {};
\path[name intersections={of = P and Y, by=x0}]
    node[dot,label=0:$y_0$] at (x0)  {};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!

Comment: @DON, if image is great, than you can upvote it (by clicking on triangle at top left side of answer) and even accept it by clicking on check mark at the same place :-)